# In Agilefant tool for Scrum, what are "Leaf Stories"?

Tags: scrum

I'm just starting as a Scrum Master, and I am looking for a good web based tool for a story board.  I am trying Agilefant, and they have something called "leaf stories".

I wonder what do they mean by that.

I've read about User Stories, Technical Stories, Unplanned Items, but I can't seem to find a reference to "Leaf Stories".  ¿Can anyone clarify?

Comment: They're stories about how the team starts off the season great, but then every damn year by miss the play-offs. And people *still* pay outrageous amounts for tickets. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.methodsandtools.com/tools/tools.php?agilefant) is a bit of a description:

> The release, or project, view also
>   contains a story tree, which is a
>   sub-set of the product backlog,
>   consisting of the stories, which have
>   been assigned to the given release.
>   During other sessions, the PO and the
>   technical team continue to refine the
>   "what’s hot right now" story. From
>   previous iterations in Agilefant, they
>   can see that the team can complete
>   around 15 story points per iteration.
>   Thus, the story is split to 10 child
>   stories, which are estimated to be
>   less than 10 story points each. These
>   10 stories are small enough to be
>   implemented in iterations, and don’t
>   need to be split to finer pieces. In
>   Agilefant these stories are called
>   leaf stories. Leaf stories are stories
>   with no child stories. They are the
>   leaves of a tree, whereas their parent
>   stories are the branches.

Please edit your question if that doesn't seem like a good answer.  I don't think it is a general Scrum term but rather something specific to the tool if you notice the 3rd last sentence from the quote.

Answer (score 4):

Leaf stories are not part of Scrum.

Within Scrum there are three types of ways to represent work:

- Epic
- Feature
- Story

Epics consist of features, which consist of stories.

Many times stories are broken down into tasks (or in this case what Agilefant must be  calling Leaf Stories) but those aren't used as part of scrum. Tasks should not be officially tracked. From a scrum point of view, the story is what is the center of the work that gets done.